# Php skips first MySQL row. Not the common double fetch() mistake

Tags: php, mysql, row, skip

**Hello everyone**

I bring forth the following issue:
My php code skips the first mysql row when printing it onto the screen. I have already seen that the issue is solved by removing a double fetch() method outside the while() loop on other questions, but I fail to see that happening here, so what else could it be? Im lost.

This is the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "standup";
$database = "sakila";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully<br><br>";
$query = "select * from actor;";
$queryResult = $conn->query($query);
while($queryRow = $queryResult->fetch_row()){
    echo "$queryRow[1]<br>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

This is the original database:

[Mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTN4d.png)

And this is the result in a browser

[Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmkCZ.jpg)

Comment: [0] is the first row, not [1]

Comment: Nah [1] is getting the column not the row

Comment: Yes, [1] is the column.

Comment: @Mike oops, you're right

Comment: set a sort order; try limit 1 <do you get 0 rows?;

Comment: @rtfm "select * from actor limit 1;" returns the very first correct row, I think you are getting somewhere :O

Comment: Try following the procedural style here - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php I think that in a sense you are calling it twice because you skip the first result when you call `$conn->query($query)` .. worth a shot

Comment: view page source maybe the row is there but the browser\html is 'hiding' it. you should always include a `sort by` or you can get unexpected results

Comment: @rtfm do you mean `order by`?

Comment: @brianforan Procedural style solved it: $queryResult = mysqli_query($conn, $query); did not skip the first row, thank you very much. I dont want to ruin the parade but what if must use object oriented style? Or would that be another questio on here?

Comment: cool, I was starting to think that that wasn't the fix. I think you may have just fixed something else in your code and it worked.. next step is to fix that background image ;)

Comment: really something else is going on, simply switching to procedural is not the answer - or every site using OOP out there would be broke.

Comment: @rtfm You sir are correct, I have not edited my "solved" comment, It looked like a fix switching to procedural, but I didnt notice the limit 100 was still there, once the limit was removed, procedural style still skips first row.

Comment: so still broke? what's the actual query used now?

Comment: How do I write code inside these comments? the query right now is $query = "select * from actor order by actor_id;"; and it does not skip the first row, must I always order by and also know the name of that column?

Comment: yes you need to use order by (especially with a limit), there is no default ordering by the db. code in comments surround with `back-ticks`

Comment: @rtfm Thank you very much, `$query = "select * from actor order by actor_id;";` fixed it, and the back-ticks worked like a charm ty for that too. Will you post it as answer or something so I can credit you? or whats next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer provided by @rtfm in the comments

**Solution 1**
Add `order by` to the query, in this situation `$query = "select * from actor order by actor_id;";` solved the issue of skipping the first row.

**Solution 2**
Add `limit` to the query, in this situation `$query = "select * from actor limit 100;";` solved the issue of skipping the first row also.